# Kendo-UI Chart error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to show a KendoUI Chart inside a DIV and looks what the LOG says:

Invalid negative value for  attribute width="-10px"

This is the code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
            theme: "Metro",
            legend: {
                position: "right",
                labels: {
                    font: "12px arial",
                    color: "white"
                },
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: "",
            },
            dataSource: data,
            series: [
                {
                    type: "pie",
                    field: "itemTotal",
                    categoryField: "itemNameAndTotal",
                    explodeField: "exploded"
                }
            ],
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "${ category }"
            }
        });
```

This is the css:

```
#chart {
    background: #f9a600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at your data and see if any of the itemTotal has a negative value.

Comment: What data are you using? Can you post a sample here.